# Cannot get formats and formulas to copy down to last row

Tags: excel, format, copy, range, rows

I'm inserting an unknown number of rows between two placeholders that I need (essential to operations elsewhere in the workbook). Cannot get the formats to copy down. I think the first two subs can be ignored, but wanted to show full context. .Copyformat is not working.

```
Sub StripData()

Call InsertData
Call FormatData
'Call DragData

End Sub

Sub InsertData()

Dim myWb As Workbook
Dim myRowsToCopy As Range

Set wbtemplate = Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw")
Set formatrange = Range("B2:CE2")
Set formularange = Range("AK2:CE2")
Set myWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Practice\Data_Pull_Dummy.xlsx")

With myWb.Sheets("Data").Range("A:XFD")
    Set myRowsToCopy = Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count))
End With

myRowsToCopy.Copy
wbtemplate.Range("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub

Sub FormatData()

Dim wbtemplate As Workbook
Set template = Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw")
template.Range("B2:CE2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Raw").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-7)

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Copyformat` is nowhere in the code? Also, why would you qualify some objects but not others? And you don't even use the variable you declared when you set it immediately after??

Comment: because i have no idea what i'm doing. an no, copy format is not in the code because it isn't working.

Comment: listen, i have no clue what i'm doing. this is the best i've been able to string together. so if you'd like to help, help. write the code yourself if you're just gonna judge mine. i did not leave .copyformat in the code or paste it here because it did not work. i know it doesn't work. because i tried and got errors with it in there.